# Recognize "generic" objects

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I'm working on a project for visually impaired people that converts the visual world to audio.

We prefer to create a prototype that doesn't need an internet connection. So we chose to work with OpenCV. After reading (a lot of) tutorials and documentation we were able to train OpenCV in recognizing specific objects. 
For example: we trained OpenCV to recognize a certain chair and a door. That works fine.

But, we also tried to train OpenCV on a "generic" level. It should be possible to recognize (almost) all chairs. We did that by training OpenCV with a lot of positive and negative images as explained here: http://coding-robin.de/2013/07/22/train-your-own-opencv-haar-classifier.html

The actual result wasn't what we expected -he could not recognize any chair-. I know, there are a lot of different parameters to take into account (maybe we did something wrong with that) and we experimented a lot. But our time (and unfortunately our knowledge of opencv) is limited.

We are looking for some advice on how to train opencv to recognize generic objects. 
Where do we start? 
Is opencv even suited to do that?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Open CV is the library to use. But object recognition is tricky. Often when people say they are doing "object recognition" they are not, they are processing one image, or at best a series of related images, to separate into object and background.

To recognise a "chair" - everything from an armchair to a dining chair to a throne - would be almost impossible. I'd want at least stereo images to give a chance to detect flat surfaces. I don't doubt that with a lot of work you can get quite a good result, maybe just recognising dining -style chairs, but it's skilled work, it's not just a  case of feeding a few parameters to a hierarchical classifier.